# when I disable window.onwheel event, it makes all object.onwheel events disabled too in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, events

When I mouseover  DIV I want to make a window wheel-scrolling disabled and make a purple square wheel-scrolling enabled. It works well in Chrome and IE11 but doesn't work in Firefox.

Firefox

```
 window.onwheel = function() {return false;};
```

seem to make all object.onwheel events disabled as well, why?
Try to scroll by mousewheel over the div and outside the div in Chrome and FF. (Firefox blocks purple square onwheel event).
https://jsfiddle.net/devrafalko/wen7sgoa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the target

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName==="HTML") {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: you gave me right tip, I modified your code and it works, thank you!